# How to display an image in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, image, silverlight-3.0

This should be simple, but...

I created a folder in my solution called Images.  I dragged an image into it.  How do I now display this image on a Page or View?

Comment: By "solution" you mean "project" right?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the image is set as a Resource. It can be in any folder in any of your projects in your solution.

You can then reference this as **[assembly];component/[path]/[imagename.extension]**

For example:

```
<Image Source="/mynamespace.myassembly;component/ResourcesFolder/image.png" Width="16" Height="16" />
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to get at it--here's the way that involves setting the image as a `Resource` in the Visual Studio file properties:

```
using (var stream = Application.GetResourceStream(
    new Uri("SilverlightAssemblyName;component/Images/myImage.png", 
            UriKind.Relative)))
{
    // read from stream
}
```

Where `SilverlightAssemblyName` is replaced by the Assembly Name you specified in the Silverlight tab of your Silverlight project.

If you want to use the image in code:

```
var bitmap = new BitmapImage();
bitmap.SetSource(stream);
myImageControl.ImageSource = bitmap;
```

Or, if you want to use the resource in XAML, you don't need any of the code:

```
<Image Source="/Images/myImage.png" Width="16" Height="16" />
```